# Postfix / sasldb : "authentication failure"

Tags: postfix, sasl, saslauthd

I'm not a postfix expert... I'm having an authentication problem with posfix 3.5 on debian 11.8.

I've added a test user :

```
# saslpasswd2 -c test
Password: test
```

Using swaks to test authentication to postfix, I get the following error :

```
# swaks --to root --server 172.31.0.69:25 --auth LOGIN
Username: test
Password: test
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
*** No authentication type succeeded
```

Logs :

```
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-xxx.localdomain
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-PIPELINING
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-SIZE 10240000
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-VRFY
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-ETRN
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-8BITMIME
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250-DSN
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 250 CHUNKING
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: watchdog_pat: 0x55af645786d0
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: < unknown[172.31.0.69]: AUTH LOGIN
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: xsasl_cyrus_server_first: sasl_method LOGIN
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: xsasl_cyrus_server_auth_response: uncoded server challenge: Username:
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: < unknown[172.31.0.69]: dGVzdA==
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: xsasl_cyrus_server_next: decoded response: test
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: xsasl_cyrus_server_auth_response: uncoded server challenge: Password:
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: < unknown[172.31.0.69]: dGVzdA==
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: xsasl_cyrus_server_next: decoded response: test
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: warning: unknown[172.31.0.69]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
postfix/smtpd[3144881]: > unknown[172.31.0.69]: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
```

An authentication test via testsaslauthd works :

```
# testsaslauthd -s smtp -u test -p test
0: OK "Success."
```

Same thing with telnet :

```
# telnet 172.31.0.69 25
Trying 172.31.0.69...
Connected to 172.31.0.69.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 xxx.localdomain ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
HELO xxx.com
250 xxx.localdomain
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
dGVzdAo=
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
dGVzdAo=
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure
```

[main.cf]

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no                                                         

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relayhost = XXX
smtp_fallback_relay = XXX
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
#inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = ipv4
recipient_delimiter = +

inet_interfaces = all
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
permit_sasl_authenticated reject
                                                                                
# auth
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix/sasl

debug_peer_list = 172.31.0.69
```

[sasl/smtpd.conf]

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
auxprop_plugin: sasldb
aslech_list: CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
```

[/etc/default/saslauthd]

```
START=yes
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
PARAMS="-m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
```

**Edit 1**

[/etc/mailname]

```
backup6
```

users:

```
# sasldblistusers2 
test@backup6: userPassword
```

**Edit 2**

-r removed in saslauthd configuration. According to the documentation, "*-r Combine the realm with the login (with an '@' sign in between). e.g. login: "foo" realm: "bar" will get passed as login: "foo@bar". Note that the realm will still be passed, which may lead to unexpected behavior.*"

[/etc/default/saslauthd]

```
START=yes
MECHANISMS="sasldb"
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
PARAMS="-m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Then swaks works :

```
# swaks --to root --server 172.31.0.69:25 --auth LOGIN
Username: test@backup6
Password: test
[...]
235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
```

But telnet still fails with username test@backup6 (base64 encoded).

Comment: It sends the username *and* the realm, i.e. `test@$myhostname` (substituted, of course) to the SASL library, not just `test`. Are you sure you use the realm `$myhostname`? What happens it you test it adding `... -r $myhostname` (here you must substitute it yourself)? What realm is used by default in saslauthd and saslpasswd2 (bring its configuration here for reference too)? Check with `sasldblistusers`. // By the way: don't enable authentication for a default service on port 25. Only do so for a submission or/and smtps service.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you for your reply. This is a test server, but TLS is planned. Post edited (-r removed from saslauthd configuration).

Comment: And if you put `smtpd_sasl_local_domain = backup6` (or whatever realm it does have) and use just `test` username? Or, unset this setting (I don't get why you have it set in the first place) and try again with `test@backup6`? Because, you know, it probably sends `test@$myhostname@backup6` with the current configuration.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov it works... thanks for the hints !

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, the username *and* the realm are sent to the SASL library.

`-r` was removed from saslauthd configuration (unexpected behavior ; the realm is still sent), and `smtpd_sasl_local_domain` can be forced to test behavior.

With this configuration, swask authenticates and so does telnet. For telnet, the error was a base64 encoding error (sorry!). As a reminder, use `-n` in echo to base64 encode without the line break :

```
echo -n $USERNAME | base64
```